# Invoke getter setters of IntDef from external class

Tags: java, android

Enums are dangerous during runtime since it causes memory leaks so Im using  IntDef. Following is my code

```
public class TestRec {

@IntDef({Mode.DAY_MODE, Mode.NIGHT_MODE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@interface  Mode {
    int DAY_MODE = 0;
    int NIGHT_MODE = 1;

}

@Mode
static int mCurrentMode = Mode.DAY_MODE;



@Mode
public static int getCurrentMode() {
    return mCurrentMode;
}

public  void setCurrentMode(@Mode int mCurrentMode) {
    this.mCurrentMode = mCurrentMode;
}
}
```

Now, I would like to `setCurrentMode` from an external class where I have to pass Mode as a parameter but Im not able to do so. Hence Im not able to invoke `setCurrentMode` from external class. what am I missing?

Comment: `setCurrentMode` should be static (because it's a setter for a static field), and should say `TestRec.mCurrentMode` instead of `this.mCurrentMode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `mCurrentMode` is a static field, not an instance field, it doesn't make sense to have an instance method as its setter. Also, it doesn't make sense to reference it as `this.mCurrentMode`, since `this` would be an instance, and it's not an instance field.

You could write your setter as a static method like this:

```
public static void setCurrentMode(@Mode int mCurrentMode) {
    TestRec.mCurrentMode = mCurrentMode;
}
```

and call it with

```
TestRect.setCurrentMode(whatever);
```